# Why is retrieval from NSUserDefaults failing for my custom object?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I have a class `PredicPair` which inherits from `NSCoding` and `NSObject` as such:

```
class PredicPair: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var weight : Float
    var prediction : String

    init(weight: Float, prediction: String) {
        self.weight = weight
        self.prediction = prediction

        super.init()
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(weight, forKey: "weight")
        aCoder.encode(prediction, forKey: "prediction")
    }

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let unarchivedWeight = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "weight") as! Float
        let unarchivedPrediction = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "prediction") as! String

        self.init(weight: unarchivedWeight, prediction: unarchivedPrediction)
    }

    class func saveToUserDefaults(pairs: [PredicPair]) {
        let dataBlob = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: pairs)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(dataBlob, forKey: "test")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    class func loadFromUserDefaults() -> [PredicPair]? {
        guard let decodedNSDataBlob = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "test") as? NSData,
            let loadedFromUserDefault = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decodedNSDataBlob as Data) as? [PredicPair]
            else {
                return nil
        }

        return loadedFromUserDefault
    }
}
```

I am trying to store an array of the class in `UserDefaults` and retrieving it, but the latter always returns nil. Any reason why?

```
let predicPair1 = PredicPair(weight: 0, prediction: "there")
let predicPair2 = PredicPair(weight: 1, prediction: "hello")

let array = [predicPair1, predicPair2]

PredicPair.saveToUserDefaults(pairs: array)
if let retreivedArray = PredicPair.loadFromUserDefaults() {
    print("loaded \(retreivedArray.count) players from NSUserDefaults")
} else {
    print("failed")
}
```

I've also tried saving to a file using `NSKeyedArchiver` but retrieval fails as well.

Comment: Try `let unarchivedWeight = aDecoder.decodeFloat(forKey: "weight")`.

Comment: @MartinR still returns nil :(

Comment: Actually your code *crashes* in my test, and works correctly when using `decodeFloat`, so there must be something else.

Comment: Also I wonder if that is your real code, because the parameter in saveToUserDefaults() should be "players", not "pairs", otherwise it does not compile.

Comment: @MartinR that is my real code but I just changed the name of two things when copying the code on here

Comment: I'm using a playground in Xcode 8 beta 6, would that affect anything? @MartinR. And would you mind sharing your correct code so I can test it out in the playground?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121820/discussion-between-cyril-and-martin-r).

Comment: Try it in a compiled project. The only change I made is to use `decodeFloat` as in my first comment.

Comment: @MartinR will do, thank you for your time!

Comment: @MartinR alright that seems to work, I'm confused.. NSUserDefaults fails silently with a playground?

Comment: It works for me even in a Playground ...

Comment: @MartinR Still failing for me in the Playground but works in the Xcode project